# Where can I find historical College Scorecard Data

Tags: data-request, collegescorecard

In September 2016 there was an update to the Scorecard Data. See here:

https://collegescorecard.ed.gov/data/changelog/

Is it possible to access data before the update? Or the original data when the Scorecard went live?

Comment: I think the large data set includes historical data. Does the consumer website display the last year data was available? For example, for median income after 10 years?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the Wayback Machine is your friend.
[data on 2015-09-15 - Original Data](https://web.archive.org/web/20150915193613/https://collegescorecard.ed.gov/data/)
[data on 2016-06-17 - Updated Data](https://web.archive.org/web/20160617230306/https://collegescorecard.ed.gov/data/)